# Adding worksheet and writing HTML content into it

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2005

I am currently working on some reports,which will be extracted in MSSQL DB. Where I will be building all my data in HTML tags and later creating a excel file with this data

```
EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @FS OUT  
IF @OLEResult <> 0 PRINT 'Scripting.FileSystemObject'  

--Open a file  
execute @OLEResult = sp_OAMethod @FS, 'OpenTextFile', @FileID OUT, @FileName, 8, 1  
IF @OLEResult <> 0 PRINT 'OpenTextFile'  

--Write Text1  
execute @OLEResult = sp_OAMethod @FileID, 'Write', Null, @Text1  

IF @OLEResult <> 0 PRINT 'WriteLine'  

EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OADestroy @FileID  
EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OADestroy @FS
```

In the above given code, `@FileName` is the filename and the DB server location where the file needs to be saved after generation. `@Text1` is the HTML content to be written in the file.

The above mentioned code, directly writes the content into the first sheet of excel. Now, I need to have something called as `@Text2` which needs to be written into 2nd sheet of same excel.

or, Is there any way I can append contents of both the sheets with some HTML tags, so that, above code remains same but, `@Text1` will have content of both the sheets.

Please suggest a way for doing this. Please ask if you need any more details on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, do you already have a way to create multiple worksheets, in the same Excel file?  If not... I have not done this, but I've seen references to it:  try googling `sp_OAGetProperty "worksheets.Add"`  I saw an example of it in use here, on [Phil Factor's site](https://www.simple-talk.com/content/print.aspx?article=344)

Comment: Also, since your tags say you're on sql-server-2005... and if you have the freedom to choose your approach... consider using SSIS to extract to Excel.  In SSIS, the Excel file is the "connection object", and each worksheet is a "table" within that Excel connection object.  Similar in ADO: each worksheet is considered a "table".

Comment: @Doug_Ivison : I do not have any way to add worksheets into the same excel file.?  I will check with the one you suggested.

Comment: Got it... and if you're *interested* in knowing more about how to do that in SSIS, I'll give more detail.

Comment: @Doug_Ivison : Its not possible in this context i guess.. I have added a line `EXEC @OLEResult=sp_OAGetProperty @FileID,'worksheets.Add',@objWorkSheet1 OUT` But, this never gives positive result, since it accpets on workbookid for adding a sheet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40644/discussion-between-pavan-kumar-and-doug-ivison)

Comment: @Doug_Ivison : look into this fiddle which has a procedure. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17ff7). This also gives some error and does not geerate any file.

Comment: Is it the same error message you got before?... which looked like a problem in the first step--the sp_OACreate.  In any case, as I pointed out in chat, how about adding `sp_OAGetErrorInfo` to get complete information on your error?  For docs **[click here](http://www.eps-cs.com/pdf/whitepaper_extending_tsql.pdf)** or for an example **[click here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Miscellaneous/callingcomfromtsql/2085/)**.